# I have tried debugging this code but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python

This is a simple exception handling problem in Python. I have tried taking the inputs a and b using the map() but I don't understand why I'm getting the following error.

My solution:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    try:
        print(a//b)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error Code: ", e)
```

Input:

```
3
1 0
2 $
3 1
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 3, in <module>
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$'
```

Comment: Don't trap for BaseException. It doesn't do what you think it does. It is provided precisely to provide for exceptions that normal code *should not* trap. Trap for `Exception` instead.

Comment: Yeah. I can also use specific exception if required, right?

Comment: The more specific the better. Regard `Exception` as the most unspecific allowable, unless you are subclassing `Iterator` or something equally abstruse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> int('$')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$'
```

---

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

this line here tries to cast input to int and your second line input has $ which is not a valid integer. You should have that part in a try except too, like:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    try:
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error Code: ", e)
        continue
    try:
        print(a//b)
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error Code: ", e)
```